# ASP.Net Registration Page - how to get foreign key from another table

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2013

I am creating an ASP.net website using Visual Studio 2013.  Specifically, I am trying to register a customer and insert the data in the customer table at the same time.  When I register a customer, I also want to get the user id for that customer (which is inserted into my user accounts table in the database).  So essentially I need to get the user id but also need to make sure that is the user id of the current user.

Here's what I tried to do:

```
String userQueryStr = "SELECT UserAccountID FROM UserAccounts WHERE Username = " + Email.Text;
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand selectCommand = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(userQueryStr, conn);
int userID = Convert.ToInt32(selectCommand.ExecuteScalar());
```

Email is the username btw.  Essentially I am trying to make sure the Username field in the UserAccounts matches what is typed in the textbox on the registration page.
Then I tried to store an insert statement and also pass the userID int variable which is storing the Current user id from the User Account Table.
My problem is, after I run the application when I click the Registration button I get this error when I type the username test@testers.com:

An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in        System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: The multi-part identifier "test@testers.com" could  not be bound.  The exception is thrown at this line:

```
int userID = Convert.ToInt32(selectCommand.ExecuteScalar());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sql thinks your email is a field, because you don't have quotes before and after

```
String userQueryStr = "SELECT UserAccountID FROM UserAccounts WHERE Username =     '" + Email.Text+"'";
```

Comment: Now I am getting another error.  It says:                                                           An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first.                               The error occurs at this line:  cmd1.ExecuteReader();                              I am using 2 SQLCommands in the same method.  Is that the issue?

Comment: Also in case you need it, here is my insert statement for customers:                 querystr1 = "INSERT INTO Customers (FirstName, LastName, StreetAddress1, Phone, City, State, UserID)" +
                "VALUES ('" + FirstName.Text + "','" + LastName.Text + "','" + StreetAddress.Text + "','" + Phone.Text + "','" + City.Text + "','" + State.Text + "','" + userID + "')";

Comment: Actually I figured it out.  All I had to do was close the connection after the 1st insert statement and reopen it before the 2nd insert statement.  Thanks for the help.